# No power to the GFCI at end of run

Tags: wiring

The two GFCI in the kitchen at the end of a run had no power.  Took them out and noticed no voltage coming into the line run GFCI (so no power to end GFCI either).  The 15 amp circuit breaker for this run indicates that multiple non-GFCI outlets precede the two GFCIs at the end of the run. All of the non-GFCI outlets are working...   I am assuming the line feed from the last non-GFCI outlet prior to the GFCI has been lost (shorted)... if this is right how best to find the short?

Comment: If it was shorted your breaker would be tripping. So you're looking for a break or open-circuit, not a short.

Comment: Open up the previous box in the chain and have a look-see.

Comment: If you have two GFCI's on a single run, you have too many.  Plug something (night light) into every GFCI in your house and get them all working.   One at a time, push TEST on each GFCI.  This will knock out power at that GFCI.  Now check all your other GFCIs.  If any of them also lost power when you did that, replace those with a plain receptacle, and mark the cover "GfCI Protected".  Now you have a handful of GFCI receptacles you can use to protect other parts of your house.

Comment: GFCI'S wired in series as you are MUST be reset in the order they appear on the circuit.  (Because the reset button won't work if the unit is not receiving power.). Chances are you just need to find all figure the order.  You should still update as @Harper describes, but with this tip you may be able to get them all back on for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have NO Voltage on Line In at the GFCI - and I am talking the PHYSICAL WIRE and not the receptacle plug - then given you have power at the preceding receptacle and not at the GFCI - you have an OPEN circuit.

That means the wire is not feeding power due to a open connection or broken connection on the preceding receptacle or on the 1st GFCI.

> Why you have the second GFCI I am not sure and ordinarily you would
>   place the GFCI first in the line and all other circuits down line from
>   the GFCI are protected no need for additional GFCI's in that circuit
>   run.

I think there are also some issues with placing a secondary GFCI in line with an existing GFCI, either one or both GFCI's might not work properly.

If it is at the receptacle end where you are measuring no voltage - the GFCI has tripped. Given you have two at the end of the run - is the other one tripped ?